# JS Matching Game Randomizes all but Last Card

Tags: javascript, css

I've set up a simple matching game using JavaScript to gather the cards in an array and then randomly repopulate the page. Everything seems to be working great except for one thing; the last image always stays the same. I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's a link to the game: http://hdesigns.x10.mx/matching/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.random` returns a number between 0 and .9 repeating. Never 1.

Change

```
var idx = Math.floor((Math.random() * (deck.length-1)));
```

to

```
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
```

on `line 98` of `main.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
```

Instead of:

```
var idx = Math.floor((Math.random() * (deck.length - 1))));
```